# What is the difference between an MIU and Interface port?

Tags: dark-heresy-2e

Long story short, What is the difference between an MIU and Interface port? What situation would you use either in and how do they work lore wise?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the actual rules are spread out between systems (Rogue Trader and onwards) and even then not very clear. Lore wise an MIU is a series of connections that allow direct control of certain devices, generally something large and unwieldy (Titans are controlled via MIU) or more importantly in this context something that is attached to the character via an MIU Weapon Interface implant. The main question for your GM is what weapons can be attached to the MIU Weapon Interface, as it says it's usually a shoulder mount but otherwise doesn't get into the specifics.

The interface port says that it lets devices plug in to your character via some standard data cable, those devices also being determined mostly by your GM. The fact that the interface port references data spools and searching systems for information gives some clue however, mainly pointing towards your 40k equivalent of personal computers or servers.